Windows 11 Taskbar Icon Not Match File Icon
The EXE file '360 DFV STITCHER xxx.exe' was created using Pyinstaller. The Taskbar shows the GUI LOGO icon 'logo.png' and the EXE file shows the icon '360_stitcher.ico'.
What was attempted to solve problem:
Delete icon cache
Restarted Windows Explore
Opened '360 DFV STITCHER xxx.exe'
Icons are mismatched.
Here is the Pyinstaller code:
pyinstaller --windowed --add-data "logo.png;." --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\Guide_Normal.png;." --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\Guide_Edit_Preset.png;."  --icon="C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\360_stitcher.ico" --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\default_2016.txt;."  --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\default_2017.txt;."  --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\default_other.txt;."  --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\preset_2016.txt;."   --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\preset_2017.txt;."   --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\preset_other.txt;."   --add-data "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\preset_Choose Preset.txt;." --add-binary "C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\360 DF_EYE VID STITCHER\ffmpeg.exe;."   --version-file version.txt "360 DFV STITCHER xxx.py"




Probably a matter of icon resolution - Windows icon files may contains multiple icons for multiple resolutions and both your cases do not use the same resolution. Please post online your icon file (360_stitcher.ico?) for a final answer (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

EXE file icon file link link

Screen test CTRL key+Roll Mouse link

@CANJMP: This icon is not the answer. Could you post the entire .exe?

I created a simple Python file with GUI single button and def function named 'test_path.py', then converted it to an EXE using Pyinstaller. I assigned it the same icon as the earlier problemed EXE file. When I open 'test_path.exe' the Taskbar displays not the '360_stitcher.ico' but instead the GUI logo which is the default feather. I will investigate Pyinstaller for this behavior.

Simply MS Windows always uses the window icon in the Taskbar. To get around this to have the Taskbar show a different icon from the EXE Window we need to create a hidden window with the icon we need in the Taskbar. The child 'on top' window  will use a different icon than the parent hidden window.
This is all done in the Python code prior to converting to an EXE file.
Example Python code:
{
Example hidden parent window and visible child window
import os
import tkinter as tk
import time
basedir = os.path.dirname(file)
try:
from ctypes import windll  # Only exists on Windows.
myappid = "mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version"
windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)

except ImportError:
pass
def on_close():
hidden_window.destroy()  # Close hidden_window when root_window is closed
def main_window():
# Create the main window with the button
root_window = tk.Toplevel()
root_window.title("Main Window")
def handle_button_press(event):
    time.sleep(6)
    on_close()

button_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(basedir, "gear_19713.png"))
button = tk.Button(root_window, text="My simple app.", image=button_icon)
button.bind("<Button-1>", handle_button_press)
button.pack()

# Set main window icon
image_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(basedir, "logo.png"))
root_window.iconphoto(False, image_icon)

root_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)  # Call on_close when root_window is closed

root_window.mainloop()

Create a hidden window without a button and LOGO 'gear_19713.png'
hidden_window = tk.Tk()
hidden_window.title("Hidden Window")
Set main window icon
image_icon_hidden = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(basedir, "gear_19713.png"))
hidden_window.iconphoto(False, image_icon_hidden)
Set size to 0x0 pixels
hidden_window.geometry("0x0")
Move the window off-screen
hidden_window.geometry("+10000+10000")
Connect the closing event of the main window to the on_close function
hidden_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)
main_window()
}
